# Video/graphics on Optiplex 790

Tags: display

Have an Optiplex 790 SFF. Everything works, it just won't display above 1024x790. Is there a tweak or obscure driver I need to fix this? It's not going to be used for gaming, etc.

Comment: and you use the on-board graphics? Cuz its the graphics card holding you back on this. Oh and you better find out the output on the PCI slot. It could be a mere 30kw and at best it would hold something like a GT1030 (not enough to run netflix that demands at least a GT1050).

Comment: These do not have expansion slots other than a small port inside. Just need to make it go to a higher resolution with the on board video sub-system and Ubuntu driver.

Comment: Oh? it should have 2x PCI-e x16(?)

Comment: Yes, but they are for internal peripherals, like SSDs and modems.